# if i didn't call the stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges of CLLocationManager,will it continue work forever?

Tags: ios

If i didn't call the stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges,will it continue work forever?Or the os will stop it automatically?(Especially in the background mode)thanks,I am a Chinese,my english may read weird..

Answer (score 1):

From the apple [developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html):

> If you leave the significant-change location service running and your iOS app is subsequently suspended or terminated, the service automatically wakes up your app when new location data arrives. At wake-up time, the app is put into the background and you are given a small amount of time (around 10 seconds) to manually restart location services and process the location data. (You must manually restart location services in the background before any pending location updates can be delivered, as described in Knowing When to Start Location Services.) Because your app is in the background, it must do minimal work and avoid any tasks (such as querying the network) that might prevent it from returning before the allocated time expires. If it does not, your app will be terminated. If an iOS app needs more time to process the location data, it can request more background execution time using the beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler: method of the UIApplication class.

If the user has disabled background app refreshing for your app, the service will not run. Otherwise, it will call your app.

Comment: thanks for your answer .I have read this document before,but i think i still don't know the exact mechnizm of it.